# How to compare two strings in a different column and create new column?

Tags: mysql, sql

--->      [i.hizliresim.com/AzbbXq.jpg](http://i.hizliresim.com/AzbbXq.jpg)     <---

i wanna get the bottom table in the picture with sql query.
In the top table, the letters in the columnC response for the numbers in the ColumnB. I want to find the response letters for numbers in the ColumnA by creating ColumnNew. In the new table there would be Colid, ColumnA, ColumnB

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I edited the question, it's my first post on Stack Overflow, sorry for my mistakes and thank you for your helps and suggestion.

Comment: It is unclear what do you want to ask, please specify your question. Is it "how to execute SQL query from Java"?

Comment: i fixed it. Thank you for your interest

Comment: [Do not post links to questions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/); include the code and data in your question as text. [Do not post images of code or data](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), post as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `JOIN`(self-reference):

```
SELECT t1.ColumnB AS ColumnA, t1.ColumnC AS ColumnNEW
FROM tab t1
JOIN tab t2 
  ON t1.ColumnB =t2.ColumnA;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7ecf72a6ca53de1ffd58bc1280574c1)**

Comment: Thank you so much! it's a clever approach  what if i have id of columnA like this https://i.hizliresim.com/AzbbXq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides self joining would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.ColumnA,
    (SELECT t2.ColumnC FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ColumnB = t1.ColumnA) ColumnNEW
FROM yourTable t1;
```